# how should i scrape href links from this website?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get every products individual URL link from this link https://www.goodricketea.com/product/darjeeling-tea
.How should I do that with beautifulsoup? Is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: Please provide the code you have attempted.

Comment: This is the code I've attempted

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests as re
import pandas as pd



baseurl = 'https://www.goodricketea.com/product/darjeeling-tea'
headers = {
   'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36'
}


r = re.get('https://www.goodricketea.com/product/darjeeling-tea')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
productlist = soup.find_all('a' ,{'class':'prod_listt_all'})

for product in productlist:
    tea = product.find('href')
    print(tea)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get product links from this site, you can for example do:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.goodricketea.com/product/darjeeling-tea"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

for a in soup.select("a:has(>h2)"):
    print("https://www.goodricketea.com" + a["href"])
```

Prints:

```
https://www.goodricketea.com/product/darjeeling-tea/roasted-darjeeling-tea-250gm
https://www.goodricketea.com/product/darjeeling-tea/thurbo-darjeeling-tea-whole-leaf-250gm
https://www.goodricketea.com/product/darjeeling-tea/roasted-darjeeling-tea-organic-250gm
https://www.goodricketea.com/product/darjeeling-tea/roasted-darjeeling-tea-100gm
https://www.goodricketea.com/product/darjeeling-tea/thurbo-darjeeling-tea-whole-leaf-100gm
https://www.goodricketea.com/product/darjeeling-tea/thurbo-darjeeling-tea-fannings-250gm
https://www.goodricketea.com/product/darjeeling-tea/castleton-premium-muscatel-darjeeling-tea-100gm
https://www.goodricketea.com/product/darjeeling-tea/castleton-vintage-darjeeling-tea-250gm
https://www.goodricketea.com/product/darjeeling-tea/castleton-vintage-darjeeling-tea-100gm
https://www.goodricketea.com/product/darjeeling-tea/castleton-vintage-darjeeling-tea-bags-50-tea-bags
https://www.goodricketea.com/product/darjeeling-tea/castleton-vintage-darjeeling-tea-bags-100-tea-bags
https://www.goodricketea.com/product/darjeeling-tea/badamtam-exclusive-organic-darjeeling-tea-250gm
https://www.goodricketea.com/product/darjeeling-tea/badamtam-exclusive-organic-darjeeling-tea-100gm
https://www.goodricketea.com/product/darjeeling-tea/seasons-3-in-1-darjeeling-leaf-tea-150gm-first-flush-second-flush-pre-winter-flush
```